# Using "--interaction=batchmode" with tex4ht causes errors to go unoticed. Make does not know a file had error

Tags: errors, tex4ht, batchmode

This is a big problem. When using option `"--interaction=batchmode"` with mae4ht in order to reduce the amount of stuff printed on the terminal, I found that if a compile error happens, then Make does not stop and go to the next file. This only happens when using this option.

Without this option, make stops at the error, which is what I want.

I compared how `pdflatex` behaves with same option, I found pdflatex does generate an error to the shell and it causes it to stop even when using this option.

I can not show this using makefile here, but instead, I used a Linux bash script and used `set -e` at the top, which says to stop the script when one command inside it generates an error.  Then made a bad tex file with an error in it. Then put 2 compile commands in the script. So one would expect only the first one to run only and not the second one. Correct? And this is the case with `pdflatex`.

But with `make4ht` it keeps running and executes the two compile commands. Which means it did not generate an error.

If I remove "--interaction=batchmode" then the script stops at the error.

Here is MWE. First the latex file with an error `foo.tex`

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\begin{document}
%\begin{table}[h]
A
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here is the `build.sh` for pdflatex. I see it run the first `pdflatex`  command and not the second one, which is what I want

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# Any subsequent(*) commands which fail will cause the shell script to exit immediately

echo "command which will cause error"
pdflatex -interaction=batchmode  foo.tex

echo "If you see this message, then Why did the script not exit??"

echo "This should never get here"
pdflatex -interaction=batchmode  foo.tex
```

Now `./build.sh` gives

```
>./build.sh 
command which will cause error
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
>
```

You see, it run only once. (no output on the screen due to use of `-interaction=batchmode` which is OK)

Now compare what happens with tex4ht. Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# Any subsequent(*) commands which fail will cause the shell script to exit immediately
echo "command which will cause error"
make4ht  -ulm default -a debug  foo.tex "mathjax,htm" "-cunihtf -utf8"  "" "--interaction=batchmode"

echo "If you see this message, then Why did the script not exit??"

echo "This should never get here"

make4ht  -ulm default -a debug  foo.tex "mathjax,htm" "-cunihtf -utf8"  "" "--interaction=batchmode"
```

And now

```
>./build.sh 
command which will cause error
[INFO]    mkparams: Output dir: 
[INFO]    mkparams: Compiler: dvilualatex
[INFO]    mkparams: Latex options: -jobname='foo'  --interaction=batchmode 
....
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.15.1 (TeX Live 2023/dev) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
[INFO]    mkutils: Parse LG
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: foo.htm
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: foo.htm
[WARNING] domfilter: DOM parsing of foo.htm failed:
[WARNING] domfilter: ...ive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/figure) [char=609]
....
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion finished


If you see this message, then Why did the script not exit??

This should never get here


[INFO]    mkparams: Output dir: 
[INFO]    mkparams: Compiler: dvilualatex
[INFO]    mkparams: Latex options: -jobname='foo'  --interaction=batchmode 
...
[INFO]    mkutils: Parse LG
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: foo.htm
.....
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion finished
>
```

You see, it did not stop! It run the compile command twice. Ofcourse if I remove `"--interaction=batchmode"` then the script will stop at the error.

The above causes my recursive make now to keep going even if an error happens in one of the files, and I would not know about it. So I remove  `"--interaction=batchmode"` for now.

I like to use it as it reduces amount of screen output making it easier to see things for long build.

How to make tex4ht stop when it gets an error using "--interaction=batchmode"`, like pdflatex does? It seems` dvilualatex` is not throwing error with this mode?

TL 2022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `-a debug` parameter, which is intended for debugging, not for regular using. Use something like `-a warning` instead. It will not print full output from LateX, but it will show all errors and warnings. Also, I would use the `-m draft` parameter, as it will require only one LaTeX run, to save some time. So your build file could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# Any subsequent(*) commands which fail will cause the shell script to exit immediately
echo "command which will cause error"
make4ht  -ulm draft -a warning  foo.tex "mathjax,htm" "-cunihtf -utf8"  "" ""

echo "If you see this message, then Why did the script not exit??"

echo "This should never get here"

make4ht  -ulm draft -a warning  foo.tex "mathjax,htm" "-cunihtf -utf8"  "" ""
```

And it will produce this output:

```
command which will cause error
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename     Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./foo.tex    5        Extra \endgroup.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./foo.tex    5        LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{table}.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./foo.tex    5        Extra \endgroup.
[WARNING] domfilter: DOM parsing of foo.htm failed:
[WARNING] domfilter: /home/michal/texmf/scripts/lua/LuaXML/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/figure) [char=609]
```

As you can see, it will not continue after the error.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed if I use `-a warning` on a file with no errors, it does not display anything at all. So I have no idea on a large build with 100's of files, where it is now.  But this is not a big problem, I will change my makefile to print which file/folder it is in at the time. As long as I see the error and as long as it stops when an error happen, that is what is important.

Comment: @Nasser you can use also other values for `-a`, like `-a info`, which should still write lot of information about the compilation.

Comment: That is OK, I think `-a warning` is good enough. I just wanted to see errors and warnings, but at the same time stop the make when this happens. I just changed my Makefile to echo the command being used, so at least I see it when it finishes one file and go to the other this way. So this solved the issue. I still think there is a problem with "--interaction=batchmode" but it is not important as `-a warning` is basically replaces that functionality.

Comment: @Nasser yes, don't use `--interaction` parameter, it is set by `make4ht` depending on the log level, so you are passing it twice to LaTeX